# split cells format treatment

Tags: excel, vba

I use a simple macro, insert a "txt" file and then split it into columns

```
Sub POR_Import()
Dim ws As Worksheet, strFile As String

Call Smaz_vstup_POR

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("POR_IMPORT") 'set to current worksheet name

strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.*),*.*", , "Please select text file...")

With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strFile, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
     .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
     .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
     .Refresh
     
Call SplitPOR

i = MsgBox("Done", vbOKOnly + vbInformation)

End With
     
End Sub
```

and split

```
Sub SplitPOR()

    Sheets("POR_IMPORT").Select
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("POR_divide").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="¦", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 2), Array(5, _
        2), Array(6, 2), Array(7, 2), Array(8, 2), Array(9, 2), Array(10, 2), Array(11, 2), Array(12 _
        , 2), Array(13, 2), Array(14, 2), Array(15, 2), Array(16, 2), Array(17, 2), Array(18, 2), _
        Array(19, 2), Array(20, 2), Array(21, 2), Array(22, 2), Array(23, 2), Array(24, 2), Array( _
        25, 2), Array(26, 2), Array(27, 2), Array(28, 2), Array(29, 2), Array(30, 2), Array(31, 2), _
        Array(32, 2), Array(33, 2), Array(34, 2), Array(35, 2), Array(36, 2), Array(37, 2), Array( _
        38, 2), Array(39, 2), Array(40, 2), Array(41, 1), Array(42, 2), Array(43, 2), Array(44, 2), _
        Array(45, 2), Array(46, 2), Array(47, 2), Array(48, 2), Array(49, 2), Array(50, 2), Array( _
        51, 2), Array(52, 2), Array(53, 2), Array(54, 2), Array(55, 2), Array(56, 2), Array(57, 2), _
        Array(58, 2), Array(59, 2), Array(60, 2), Array(61, 2), Array(62, 2), Array(63, 2)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        
End Sub
```

But every time I want to repeat the process I have to close and reopen excel. The moment you insert the txt for the second time excel will automatically split it according to how it was split the first time.

Is there please any possible treatment for this case?

Comment: So, your query imports a text file in "POR_IMPORT" sheet, then copy the column B:B (the necessary to be processed) in A:A of "POR_divide" sheet, then process it (split). Do you say that saving the workbook, next time you open it, the data in  "POR_divide" sheet is changed?

Comment: not unless I close excel and just delete columns in both POR_IMPORT and POR_DIVIDE.. the next time I run the macro to insert data, the data in POR_IMPORT are already split according to the spl function. Only when I close excel and reopen can I use the function to insert data again

Comment: I am afraid, I cannot get you... Since you split the data in "POR_divide", how to be the data split in "POR_IMPORT"? Do you want repeating the process, without deleting the data in "POR_divide"? Forget about closing and opening the workbook... What do you want doing **second time** without closing and reopening and it goes wrong? What does "goes wrong" mean?

Comment: I need to use the Sub POR_Import() function multiple times.

I upload the file split, next steps and again and again and again.

If I import it a second time, the data that is imported into the worksheet ("POR_IMPORT") is already split by the excel itself and an error pops up ( when splitting, there will be empty data in column "B", so the split function copies but has nothing to split in the second step)

Comment: Which part of your code splits the range in ("POR_IMPORT") sheet? `Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1")...` should be applied in sheet "POR_divide", since it works on A:A selection... Am I missing something? What error do you receive? It may be connected to the fact that a `QueryTable` already exists in that range, I think...

Comment: it splits another macro "SplitPOR" which I call after the upload. The data is then deleted, but excel remembers this and imports the split a second time which is undesirable. 

But if I close excel and reopen it, I can use the function again without any problem.

Comment: I cannot get you, sorry... First `Sub` calls **every time** the second one and the **data are split in "POR_divide"**. What "split is second time imported" does mean is over my level of understanding. I tried helping you, but I cannot. If you have a different way to answer all my above questions, I will try coming back. Otherwise, I cannot understand what you are saying, sorry...

Comment: @FaneDuru - Excel "remembers" the use of TextToColumns and will often "auto-split" any data pasted into the same source range.  This is not a case of code being called but of Excel being overly "helpful"  See for example: https://superuser.com/questions/422137/pasting-text-into-excel-without-splitting-on-spaces-or-other-delimiter or https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2511-excel-prevent-text-to-column.html

Comment: @Tim Williams I knew about this 'remenbering' of Excel in case of `TextToColumns` and I also have a piece of code able to slove it, but I asked many times if the split is done in "POR_IMPORT" sheet, where `QueryTables.Add` brings imported data . Does this peculiar behavior consider `QueryTables` import as **pasting text** and split it in the sheet according to the last `TextToColumns` used parameters? If so, I would apologize and consider myself learning something really strange...

Comment: @FaneDuru - sorry I don't know the answer to that question.

Comment: @Tim Williams when I will  have some availability I will try imagining as scenario to test the idea... I would also like that OP will confirm that behavior, too.

Comment: I just tested - the "auto-split" happens on POR_IMPORT on importing the data.

Comment: `DisableAutoSplitting` from here https://superuser.com/questions/422137/pasting-text-into-excel-without-splitting-on-spaces-or-other-delimiter worked for me to prevent the "auto-split"

Comment: @Tim Williams I officially apologize to OP! He did not dare to sustain his truth, anymore.  Even if **he was right**... I did not imagine that importing a text file can be assimilated to copying... Anyhow, I feel obliged to post something to improve his code and solve the issue... :)

Answer (score 2):

Apologize once more for being obtuse and not understanding what you meant!

Please, try using the next optimized solution:

```
Sub POR_Import()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, strFile As String

 Call Smaz_vstup_POR

 Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("POR_IMPORT") 'set to current worksheet name

 ws.UsedRange.ClearContents 'clear the previous used range content

 'Normalize the TextToColumns behavior:____________________________________________________________
 With ws.Range("A1")
    .value = "1,2,3"
    .TextToColumns Destination:=ws.Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    .ClearContents
 End With
 '____________________________________________________________________________________________

 strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.*),*.*", , "Please select text file...")

With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strFile, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
     .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
     .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
     .Refresh
 End With
 ws.QueryTables(ws.QueryTables.count).Delete 'delete the query after bringing the necessary text

SplitPOR ws 'call the splitting function with ws sheet as argument

 MsgBox "Done", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
End Sub

Sub SplitPOR(ws As Worksheet)
   Dim wsP_d As Worksheet, arrtxt(62), i As Long
   
   Set wsP_d = Worksheets("POR_divide")
   wsP_d.UsedRange.ClearContents 'clear the content, to not be ask about overwriting
   
   wsP_d.Range("A:A").value = ws.Columns("B:B").value 'copy the column without using clipboard
   
   For i = 0 To UBound(arrtxt) 'create the array to be passed to FieldInfo TextToColumns parameter
        arrtxt(i) = Array(i + 1, 2)
   Next i
   
   'Use a more compact way:
    wsP_d.Range("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=wsP_d.Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="¦", FieldInfo:=arrtxt, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it. I will feel better knowing that I could help, after my stupid approach in comments, not being able to understand how what you were saying was possible...

Comment: I only half-remembered the "auto-text-to-columns" thing and had thought it was restricted to the range where it had been previously applied.  Very surprised to find it happened on a different sheet, and with a query table...

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt work i have import file with this strucuture `XXXXXXX¦¦000005¦XXXXXX¦XXXXXX¦20062021¦21062021¦¦¦0¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦2800000¦B¦3780717¦15092050¦0¦M¦10833¦¦¦¦¦¦0¦0¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦ XXXXXX¦¦30062021¦XX¦X¦X¦XXXXXX¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦XXXXXX¦X¦¦XXX¦¦¦¦¦¦XXXXXX¦XXXXXX¦XXXXXX¦XXXXXX¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦`
if I use my import method... it will import my txt file into two columns. / it is due to a character in the txt file data separates them using ch09 (tab), but in your example it imports into one column. I have no idea how this is possible :D edit: that code from txt is one row in notepad

Comment: @Jakub So, you are talking about the import of the text file in "POR_IMPORT". Is this understanding correct? If so, the delimiter should be comma. This is in your original code and this is what the above code uses... If no comma separator, I cannot imagine how your code can differently split the text file content... Please, try using my `POR_Import` sub and your `SplitPOR` one. Take care to change the call from `SplitPOR ws` to `SplitPOR`. Does it split correctly, using comma separator, some text not containing any comma? Did you use a different file? If so, try playing with the initial one...

Comment: @Tim Williams I couldn't even imagine that it is possible. Like I said, I knew about this way of Excel guessing what you try doing and 'trying to help', but it was sticked to may brain, logically I would like to believe, that it will behave in that way if you try doing a similar operation. Copying in the same page, something with a structure similar with the one used to be split. But, I am happy I learned something...

Comment: @FaneDuru The problem is that excel remembers the last option for the column splitter. I solved the problem with a small macro that makes the column split differently ( or on the default "tab") than I require. But thanks a lot for the help , I will definitely use some of your code

Comment: @Jakub So I cannot understand what you say (again)... What Excel remembers about the column splitter does not matter, since the code tells what column splitter to use. Can you share that "small macro" you are talking about? And what about the text file lines you shared? Is there any comma, but I missed it? If not, is it a typo, you forgot placing it?

Comment: @FaneDurutest it out. When I insert TXT into excel and it contains a tabulator it automatically splits into two columns, when I use the column splitting, and I want to insert TXT again .. excel remembers this my split and according to this rule it inserts TXT (i.e. if it contains my separator it splits it when I insert txt, why this happens I don't know, but every excel does it)

So I do delete > insert > split and then I just insert the value with the macro, split the column according to "tab" and delete it immediately

Comment: This is the macro for "help" `Sub Help()

    Sheets("POR_IMPORT").Select
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "XX?X"
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, OtherChar _
        :="¦", FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
`

Comment: @FaneDuru I tested a dummy text file and it behaves correctly. Can you share one of the text file you are using? Containing only 2, 3 rows, even with dummy data...

Comment: @FaneDuru [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/13i_xHTxfAxjQwUpCzxiPtIVVLp2fTqZB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Jakub I missed this comment yesterday. Downloaded the file and I will test it...

Comment: @Jakub **The sent file is not comma separated. It is Tab separated**! Your (initial) code was wrong. **It only happened to have the `Tab` as delimiter `True` from a previous use and your code does not treat this aspect (making all the other separators `False`, as usually should be)**. I tested the code using `.TextFileTabDelimiter = True` and **it works as it should**! Your `Help` sub only repairs the logic mistake... Adapted the above code to use `Tab` as separator. Please, test it and send some feedback. Without using your helper sub...